# Dahon SUV D6 frame hinge

Tags: frames

I have a problem with the main frame hinge of dahon SUV D6 folding bike.
It is hard (stiff?) and the bike does not fold as smoothly as it should. I am trying to fix it.
But i do not Know how to UNASSEMBLE the hinge joint to fix it.
Is it possible to unassemble it? Can I fix it without unassembling it?
Either way, what tools and lubricants should I use?

I send some pictures
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You can't disassemble, it's riveted. The only possibility is to rely on the penetrating properties of oil.

Comment: I wonder if chain lube might be a good choice - it has wicking properties.  Also use a hot air blower or a hairdryer to warm the area, apply lube, and flex it.   On the other side you don't want this joint to be loose in any way - its the single pin holding your bike's halves together, and if it was sloppy your bike would be like a hissing cat arching it's back when you brake.  That's not good either!

Answer (score 2):

Oil it.

Your main hinge is a permanently assembled pin.  It is not a bolt and should not be removed.

I also notice your bike has rust marks - so I guess it has a hard life and is stored outside.  This will absolutely contribute to difficulties opening and closing the main hinge as well as shortening the overall life of your bike.

Are you following the recommended maintenance?  I expect it would say something about lubricate at least yearly, and more often in harsh conditions (like outside storage)

Comment: Even my Dahon, which is always stored in an indoor area, has trouble with the hinge when not used often enough. Trying to open and close a few times will improve that one.

Comment: @Willeke do you lubricate the kingpin?  With what ?  That would be a good answer.

Comment: No, I have never lubricated it, some reprated movement has always done the job.